# How can handle update access token when a schedule process is running?

Tags: javascript, token

I have used tokens as authentication approach of my App, and, I have defined a function as follows in my App:

```
<script>
const func1 = async ()=>{
  await fetch(api)  // a simple get request
}

const timer = ()=>{
  
  setinterval(async()=>{
     
     await func1() // invoking http request function
    

},10000)


timer()
}
</script>
```

When the timer invokes the function inside of the timer with proper interval, it might be failed due to the ending lifespan of access token.also, I have defined proper config in axios interceptors for handling errors due to the lifespan of access token, but just before updating of access token, the user recognize that the request failed.
How can handle it and preventing updating token before expiration of token?